# git clone one single file and push back to remote

Tags: git

The title might be a bit misleading. The purpose is to make a simple bash tool to change a link into a **build_options.txt** file by using a token (and not giving access to anyone else to the repo, or at least very limited). It needs to be on a specific branch (so -b i think is there) and then build a menu or give some options. After this on the remote i'll be needing that edit in order to build.

I believe the cloning is required, but in reality the need is only to modify that **build_options.txt**. I tried with *--sparse* but it seems complicated, and i'm not an advanced git user. Git version used is 1.9.1. Access is both ssh and https.

In short: run this script, have a local copy of **build_options.txt** and nothing more, then a git push origin or something similar must be possible in a different one-time-purpose branch.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Git version 1.9.1 is very old—current Git is 2.26 with 2.27 coming soon—and even in Git 2.27, the partial clone code is not ready for ordinary-people-use.  In Git versions before 2.17, partial clone doesn't exist.  What this all means is that you literally *cannot* clone a single file.

Git is built around commits.  Each commit contains a full snapshot of *every* file.  To get a single file, you get an entire commit which gets you *every* file.  To make a *new* commit, you must write a commit that stores *every* file, so even if you installed the latest Git and used partial clones, you'd still need to get a pretty-full clone, so that you have the latest version of *every* file.  There is no other option: you must get *every* file.

You *can* make a *shallow* clone, if you like; shallow clone support should work well even in ancient Git 1.9.1, I think.

In any case, once you have every file, you might as well just go with that: check out the commit, create a branch name, modify the one file, `git add` the one file, and `git commit` to make a new snapshot of *every* file.  You can now `git push` this one new commit to a new branch on `origin`.